# Propagate module imports using __all__to top

Tags: python, python-import

I want to propagate some modules(utils) to top, but also controlling what is propagated using `__all__`

For example:

There is a package `all` and what is in `__init__` are imported in `alpha_utils`, so from a user perspective the methods are like are coming from `alpha_utils`.

Also `alpha_utils` packages is imported by the module `top_utils_module`.

I want to do:

`top_utils_module.beta_fn` (even if `beta_fn` is in `all` package)
`top_utils_module.alpha_fn` (even if `beta` is in `alpha_utils` package)

I can do using always `import from <some_module_name> all` but I want to have some
control on what each module expose, by using `__all__`.

Using a structure as below is not working, I can get what I want a level down but not two levels down.

```
-- top_2 utils_module

...
+-- alpha_utils
|   -- __init__
|   -- alpha_module_1
|   -- alpha_module_2
|   -- alpha_module_3

....
+-- all
|   -- __init__
|   -- all_module_1
|   -- all_module_2
|   -- all_module_3
```

in `all` folder `__init__`:

```
from .all_module_1 import fun1, fun12
from .all_module_2 import fun2
from .all_module_3 import fun3
__all__ = ["fun1", "fun2", "fun12", "fun2", "fun3"]
```

in `alpha_utils` folder `__init__`:

```
from ..all import *
_all__ = ["alpha_module_1", "alpha_module_2", "alpha_module_3"] ## ? how to integrate ..all
```

in `top_2 utils_module`:

```
from some.tir import tir
from alpha_utils import *
```

Comment: Your problem description and expected outcome is not clear to me. In addition’ the name *`top_2 utils`* has a space in it which you can’t use in a Python module name. Assuming I can replace that space with another underscore, what is the end goal, to use `from top_2_utils import *`, which then adds `fun1`, `fun2`, ... `fun12`?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

To recap and simplify, because the question is a little noisy and hard to follow. There are 3 modules/packages.

> Glossary: [import package](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Import-Package), [module](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Module), and by *to export* I mean conveying the scope of public API of a module/package by defining a sequence of the symbol names in `__all__` module-level attribute.

- `a` -- a top level module where we want end-users to consume the API from; it
  imports everything from `b`
- `b` -- an import package that exports own modules, but also re-exports
  the symbols from the import package `c`
- `c` -- an import packages that exports individual symbols from its modules

How should `b`'s root module, `__init__.py`, look like?

### A solution

From one perspective it's a workaround, and a solution would be to change requirements and make `a` import directly specific synbols from `c`. But from another perspective, depending on yours citation of code ownership and teams' responsibility, it may be exactly what you want.

My example import package looks like this.

```
├── a.py
├── b
│   ├── bm1.py
│   ├── bm2.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── c
    ├── _cm1.py
    ├── _cm2.py
    └── __init__.py
```

- `c/__init__.py`

  For `c` I assume its modules are internal because it exports specific functions
  from them, hence they start with with an underscore.

  ```
  from ._cm1 import cm1_fn1, cm1_fn2
  from ._cm2 import cm2_fn1, cm2_fn2

  __all__ = 'cm1_fn1', 'cm1_fn2', 'cm2_fn1', 'cm2_fn2'
  ```
- `c/_cm1.py`

  ```
  def cm1_fn1(): pass
  def cm1_fn2(): pass
  ```
- `c/_cm2.py`

  ```
  def cm2_fn1(): pass
  def cm2_fn2(): pass
  ```
- `b/__init__.py`

  For `b` I assume its modules are public and have own public API.

  Note that the modification of `globals` has some risks of name clashes in the
  future. Also some code analysis tools might not understand the modification.

  ```
  from . import bm1, bm2
  from .. import c

  __all__ = ('bm1', 'bm2') + c.__all__

  _own_scope = globals()
  for name in c.__all__:
      _own_scope[name] = getattr(c, name)
  ```
- `b/bm1.py`

  ```
  __all__ = 'bm1_fn1',

  def bm1_fn1(): pass
  ```
- `b/bm2.py`

  ```
  __all__ = 'bm2_fn1',

  def bm2_fn1(): pass
  ```
- `a.py`

  ```
  from .b import *
  from .b import __all__
  ```

With this I can step out of the directory, say named `so66939804`, and run the following `python3` REPL.

```
>>> from so66939804 import a
>>> a.__all__
('bm1', 'bm2', 'cm1_fn1', 'cm1_fn2', 'cm2_fn1', 'cm2_fn2')
>>> dir(a)
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'bm1', 'bm2', 'cm1_fn1', 'cm1_fn2', 'cm2_fn1', 'cm2_fn2']
```